# Is it possible to ping your own domain name?

Tags: networking, server, dns, nginx

I know that this is probably a stupid question but I really don't know the answer.

I have a webserver with two domains sharing the same ip address.

I am using nginx with fastcgi and php5-fpm, and I haven't actually configured ip tables.

I have been trying to localise an upstream timeout error.

But the thing is I truly do not know, is it possible to ping your own domain name via ssh?

I can ping my ip address, I can ping localhost and I can ping 127.0.0.1, but I can not ping the domain name. But the thing that bothers me is I don't know if I should be able to.

Is that normal?

Comment: Would you mind adding some details on the configuration (nameserver setup, webserver firewall, etc.) as an [edit] to your question?

Comment: Can't you use a proxy and ping your external ip address?

Comment: It's a remote web server. Not a local one. And I am pinging by ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the thing is I truly do not know, is it possible to ping your own
>   domain name via ssh?

Well, by "via ssh" you mean while being logged in on the server itself? Sure you should be able to do so (if your firewall rules don't prohibit it.)

But what happens when you ping your domain name? ping can only send packages to IP addresses, so it has to resolve the domain name to an IP address. If you do that manually, for example via `dig`, you should see your public IP address:

```
$ dig www.example.com +short
93.184.216.34
```

If this doesn't work (this isn't showing your IP), you cannot ping, because your name server configuration is probably broken.

If it does work and you still cannot ping, check if you have iptable rules after all:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

There might be rules prohibiting incoming our outgoing [icmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets

Comment: iptable rules are empty. Dig responds connection timed out no servers could be reached. Ping times out as well. It is funny as this is exactly the problem that I am having. It was fine yesterday, and out of nowhere 504 errors, and running scripts won't execute as they have to address the server. Any more ideas?

Comment: Then check your dns settings, there lies your problem. Should be important for other stuff as well

Comment: I have dns configured at the domain registrar, but the ip addresses in resolv.conf are different from those at the registrar. Should I use the ip adresses as they are configured at the webhost?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanx Jakob. Thats exactly what it was. What I still don't understand is what changed. Why did it suddenly decide to stop working after running for 2 months?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
The ping will go out to nearest router and come back.

Comment: So why does the connection time out when I try to ping the domain name?

Comment: Well, there could be a rule in the iptables or a problem with your name servers.